# How to add CollectionView custom cell at the end of cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have array of images , that display in collection view , I create a cell for , when I click on last of cell that open image picker.
  -> selected image can be set in this cell, and automatic add new cell last of this.
 (I have no idea about this , please help , Thanks)

**CollectionView class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

   // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    cell.btnSelectImage.setTitle(items[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
    cell.btnSelectImage.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnSelectImage.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
                     forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        // call your alert here
    }
}
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please choose a Picture".localized, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openCamera()
    }
    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openGallary()
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel){
        UIAlertAction in
    }
    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone{
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
//MARK: - UIImagepickercontroller Method  -

func openCamera()
{
    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil
    {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        imagePicker.takePicture()

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        noCamera()
    }
}

func openGallary()
{
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
    {
       imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
       imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    }
    else
    {
       imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

    }
}
func noCamera()
{
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "ok", message: "Device has no camera".localized, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{

    let timestamp = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage


    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    let cell  = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal)


    collectionView.reloadData()

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
} 

}
```

**CollcetionViewCell**

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{

 @IBOutlet var btnSelectImage: UIButton!

}
```

-Create array for images , showing in collectionview

Comment: are you fixed your problem till now?

Comment: @SunilPrajapati YES but need batter code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE EDIT METHODS ONLY AND ADD SOME METHODS:

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var selectedImage : UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.btnSelectImage.setTitle(items[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
    cell.btnSelectImage.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
                 forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

    cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage, forState: .Normal)//setBackground image of button
    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    //because need open imagePicker only last cell
    //IF YOU WANT TO OPEN IMAGEPICKER CLICK ON BUTTON THEN ADD COMMENT BELOW LINE
    if indexPath.row == self.items.count-1 
    {
        self.configuringImagePickerController()
    }
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
   self.configuringImagePickerController()//If you want open imagepicker click on button
}

func configuringImagePickerController()
{
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please choose a Picture".localized, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openCamera()
    }

    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openGallary()
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localized, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel){
       UIAlertAction in
    }
    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
    collectionView.reloadData()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: and if not work or you need some other help then comment here

Comment: Showing popup with zoom image. When I click on other cell

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to create an `item` type object, because it is your datasource for collectionview, add that in `item` array at last and just reload collectionview.

Probably you need to do this in  `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])` method.

Edit:

```
var items = [UIImage]()
```

//may have some image objects

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

   // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
   // cell.btnSelectImage.setTitle(items[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
   // cell.btnSelectImage.tag = indexPath.row
   // cell.btnSelectImage.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
                     forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    let choosenImage = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal)
    return cell

}





func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{

   /* let timestamp = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage


    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    let cell  = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal)
*/
    let choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
    self.items.append(choosenImage)
    collectionView.reloadData()    
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: How to add image in this array , and how to display this images in cell button .?

Comment: your datasource is of string type and cell has no imageview.. how yo want to display image?

Comment: I need to image in button background ,  cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal) from image picker

Comment: items array is temp , You can also create this UIimage array , Please can you tell me how to add this image in datasource

Comment: updated answer..you have to first go through some basic tutorials before asking on SO..Try to follow appcoda, ray wenderlich or any

Comment: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not call

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
// MARK:-
var images:[Images]=[]
//MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return self.images.count+1
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
if indexPath.row == images.count{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyNewCollectionViewCell
return cell 
}
else{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
// cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
cell.btnSelectImage.setTitle(images[indexPath.row].image, forState: .Normal)
cell.btnSelectImage.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btnSelectImage.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
                 forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
return cell
}
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
if indexPath.row == images.count
{
// call the uipicker opening method here.
}}
```

Model for images received from UIImagePickerView delegate

```
class Images{
    var image:UIImage?
}
```

Comment: Thanks , that add new cell , but how I add selected images in new created cell , from image picker

Comment: create  a model to store image received from the uIImagePicker view delegate method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, and use the array of that model instead of items array. hope u get what i am trying to say ?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say, but I don't know how to create modal array.

Comment: Please give me any reference or code for this. Image is not showing in button .

Comment: please review the edited code.i have created the model for Images and also an object array for Images you just need to append images that you got from the UIImagePickerView Delegate method

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

My approach will be to to have a ***var say itemsCount initialized with 1*** instead of your ***var items which is an array***.Also have an array of images.

```
var itemsCount = 1
var images = [UIImage]()

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection  section: Int) -> Int {
 return self.itemsCount
}
```

Return the **itemsCount in data source method of collection view**.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
if indexPath.row == self.itemsCount - 1
{
    // call your alert here
}
}
```

Check if the indexPath selected is the last cell because as per your requirement, you need to show the imagePicker when the last cell is clicked.

Now to add one more cell, when image is picked successfully

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{

let timestamp = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
let choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage

//Change 1
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.itemsCount -1, inSection: 0)
self.images.append(choosenImage)
let cell  = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal)
//Change 2

self.itemsCount += 1

collectionView.reloadData()

dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Make the changes in your code marked with **Change 1** and **change 2**.
And do the caching of images because in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** you are not setting the image and new dequed cell may or may not have images. Also the images might be different based on cell dequed. To set the title you can use

```
 cell.btnSelectImage.setTitle(String(self.itemsCount), forState: .Normal)
 if images.indices.contains(indexPath.row) {
   cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(self.images[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
 }
```

**Finally it will be less expensive to insert a new cell instead of reloading the whole collection view.**

Comment: cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal) can't not work , image not showing in cell , how I set background image

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Check it. Why it is not showing, i have already explained in the last para for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: itemsCount and images are instance variables.Rest I have put with the method names. Final block will go under cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Thanks for your help I try this.

Comment: You have to set the delegate in viewDidLoad. i.e. self.imagePicker.delegate = self

Comment: Just check the update as index will start from 0 not 1. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell are not ordered filled with images, So I will suggest to use Dictionary data structure instead of  Array. Update image to items dictionary for a index path on change and then reload data.

```
var items:[Int:Any] = [1: NSNull() , 2: NSNull(), 3: NSNull(), 4: NSNull(), 5: NSNull()]
```

In delegate call :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    cell.btnSelectImage.setTitle(items[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
    cell.btnSelectImage.tag = indexPath.row

    if let choosenImage = items[indexPath.row+1] as? UIImage {
        print(choosenImage)
        cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(choosenImage, forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        cell.btnSelectImage.setBackgroundImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        print("no image exist")
    }

    cell.btnSelectImage.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
                                  forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    return cell

}
```

Update dictonary on image picker callback.

```
let choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
items.updateValue(choosenImage, forKey: yourIndexPath)
```